# Overrunning superscript in product written in “Pi notation”

Tags: math-mode, spacing

How do you deal with the problem of an overrunning superscript in a product  written in Pi notation?  E.g.

[image]

In this case it seems that the extra space before and after the Pi is unnecessary, so maybe it could be omitted?

Another solution I guess is naming the expression using a variable and use the variable name as the superscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  N_A!\prod_{k=1}^{(N_A-N_B)/2} (2k - 1)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about using `\frac{}{}` instead of `/` notation for quotient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure it looks better, but to answer the direct question, the space of the superscript can be ignored with `\mathclap` of the `mathtools` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  N_A!\prod_{k=1}^{\mathclap{(N_A-N_B)/2}} (2k - 1)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `mathtools` package also provides the `\smashoperator` macro:

[image]

You may ask what the practical difference is between this solution and the `\mathclap`-based approach that Steven Segletes used in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403586/5001). Observe that the lower bound of the `\prod` macro -- `k=1` -- is ever so slightly wider than the product symbol above it. Because the `\mathclap` directive affects only the upper limit of multiplication, there's a wee bit more whitespace on either side of the `\prod` symbol in Steven's answer than in mine.

Of course, one really has to know what to look for in order to notice this difference in the first place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
N_A! \smashoperator{\prod_{k=1}^{(N_A-N_B)/2}} (2k-1)
\]
\end{document}
```